# Dynamic font in angular 10

Tags: angular, fonts

i have two question.

1. is it possible to read and get an array of the folder assets/fonts?
2. I have a feature in my project of uploading fonts, the question is, can i have dynamic fonts? which means they are NOT declared in SCSS. i want to declare them dynamically using [ngStyle] or some other way.

i tried the following:

```
          <mat-select class="customSelect" panelClass="" disableOptionCentering="true" formControlName="font">
            <mat-option  [ngStyle]="testFont">TEST</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
```

and in .ts file

```
  testFont = {
    '@font-face' : `{
      font-family: DIN Office Medium Italic; // will  replace with variable
      src: url(assets/fonts/ + 'DINOffc-MediIta.ttf'); // will  replace with variable
    }`
}
```

is it possible? i couldn't find any solution for dynamic font at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently just done it on mine but it wasn't easy.

You can't just read the contents of a folder of fonts though. I suggest you have either an api or local json file that you can read in. The following data structure would work:

```
"fonts": [
    {
      "id": 564654746747,
      "refName": "Press Start 2P",
      "fontUpload": null,
      "filePath": "PressStart2P-Regular.ttf"
    },
    {
      "id": 1607016789736,
      "refName": "Nerko One",
      "fontUpload": null,
      "filePath": "font1607016803471.ttf"
    },
    {
      "id": 1609847399144,
      "refName": "Roboto Slab",
      "fontUpload": null,
      "filePath": "font1609847418669.ttf"
    }
  ]
```

And then to dynamically render those new fonts in your browser, send the array to this method which will create an on-the-fly stylesheet:

```
generateFontCss(arr)
        {
            var myEle = document.getElementById("fontStylesheet");
            if (myEle) {
                document.getElementById("fontStylesheet").remove();
            }

            let result = "<style>";
            result = result + "body{}";

            arr.forEach(element => {
            result = result + "@font-face {";
            result = result + "font-family: 'font"+element.id+"';";
            result = result + "src: url('"+this.gameDomain()+"/"+element.filePath+"') format('truetype');";
            result = result + "font-weight: normal;";
            result = result + "font-style: normal;";
            result = result + "}";
            });
            result = result + "</style>";
                        
            const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                const style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.id = "fontStylesheet";
                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result));
                head.appendChild(style);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. manipulating the DOM like this causes me many problems.
regarding my first question, why isn't it possible? for comparison, i have images in my assets/images folder that i can show using src binding, what is the difference?

Comment: @AsafBello manipulating the dom to show dynamic stuff like this is the only way unfortunately. But you can set a specific name for it like 'fontStylesheet' (in my example) and remove it later, it shouldn't interfere with anything else that you're doing.
Regarding your first question, if you know the exact name of the font then yes you can bind straight to it. But because you've mentioned that this is a dynamic app how are you going to ensure the app knows what's in the folder?

Comment: i thought that if i have access to a single file i also have access to the folder and all it's content, am i wrong?
i want something like: this.http.get('assets/fonts') - and to get the files list

Comment: @AsafBello you have access to a file, but you can't list out the contents of a folder in Angular. Even if you did it manually most servers also prevent this from happening as it's a security risk. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much, so i guess my only solution is an api for the list.

Comment: @AsafBello unfortunately yes. I have a working solution that works with a json file and express router. If that suits what you need, just ask another question and I can send it to you :)